# Getting the latitude and longitude from an address using pygeocoding

Tags: python, geolocation, python-2.x

It might be kinda noob to ask. Sorry about that. tried this https://github.com/mutaku/pygeocoding library and did a LookUp like so

```
print LookUp(latlng="39.9518819802915,-75.1476150197085")
```

But it gave me

> '**init**() should return None'

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do a `from pygeocoding import *` before the print ?

Comment: yeah, i did import it. otherwise it will return global name 'pygeocoding' is not defined

Comment: This is a shot in the dark. Try deleting line 87 from https://github.com/mutaku/pygeocoding/blob/master/pygeocoding/api.py and then using it.

Comment: You dont call `pygeocoding` anywhere in the sample given here. Why will it return a not defined error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a bug in that code, replace the line:

`return result`

with

```
self.result=result  #assign the result to a LookUp instance
```

and then run:

```
In [1]: from pygeocoding import *

In [2]: r=LookUp(latlng="39.9518819802915,-75.1476150197085")

In [3]: r.result
Out[3]: 

{u'results': [{u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'400',
     u'short_name': u'400',
     u'types': [u'street_number']},
    {u'long_name': u'Arch Street',
     u'short_name': u'Arch St',
     u'types': [u'route']},
    {u'long_name': u'Center City',
     u'short_name': u'Center City',
     u'types': [u'neighborhood', u'politi ....................}
```

Comment: @tipsywacky glad that helped, if possible then point out this bug to the author.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for helping tipsywacky with this. I'm the author of this project and I hadn't touched this code in quite some time and forgot a few of the issues that hadn't been fixed up. 

Working update is active with [commit here](https://github.com/mutaku/pygeocoding/commit/e4f635d06b5b356a0aae9d7d04b1e98bd560973f)

Thanks, and please feel free to add any issues/bugs to the Issues section of the project should you come across any or wish to request any features/improvements!